# Ошибка приложения Android

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-studio

Не могу скомпилить android-проект, вылетает вот такая ошибка:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                    Process: com.fitnesseyescommand.fitnesseyes, PID: 8185
>                                                    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$attr
>                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:289)
>                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:246)
>                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
>                                                        at com.fitnesseyescommand.fitnesseyes.LoadingActivity.onCreate(LoadingActivity.java:25)
>                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343)
>                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2441)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
>                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5345)
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
>                                                        at

В build.gradle вот эти зависимости:

```
compile files('src/main/java/libs/android-support-v4-22.2.1.jar')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
compile ("com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0")
compile ("com.android.support:design:22.2.0")
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно добавить в проект библиотеку `android-support-v7-appcompat`, которую вы можете найти в папке `android.library.reference.1=../android-support-v7-appcompat`

а после добавить строчку в project.properties

```
android.library.reference.1=../android-support-v7-appcompat
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, я правильно понимаю что нужно взять jar-файл библиотеки, он у меня вот тут Android\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat  и потом не совсем понятно, что вот тут прописать project.properties?